# Can't get token.remove() working in Facebook Emitter

Tags: javascript, eventemitter

Any idea why [Facebook emitter](https://github.com/facebook/emitter) is not working for `token.remove()` call below:

Console:

```
$ node main.js
5 10
/Users/carlf/Documents/dev/test/emitter/emit-node.js:21
token.remove();
      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My Code:

```
var {EventEmitter} = require('./node_modules/emitter');
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

var token = emitter.addListener('event', function(x, y) { console.log(x, y); });

emitter.emit('event', 5, 10);  // Listener prints "5 10".

token.remove();
emitter.emit('event', 9, 11); // nothing is logged
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you the remove is not a function. To remove a listener you need to call the `removeListener` method of that instance of `EventEmitter` passing the name of the event and the callback you provided. Try this:

```
var {EventEmitter} = require('./node_modules/emitter');
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

function handler(x, y) {
  console.log(x,y);
}

emitter.addListener('event', handler);

emitter.emit('event', 5, 10);  // Listener prints "5 10".

emitter.removeListener('event', handler);

emitter.emit('event', 9, 11); // nothing is logged
```

Comment: removeListener() doesn't show up in a search of the gitHub source. Also, my example with `token.remove()` is right off the Emitter gitHub page, so figure that should work.

Comment: @GiantElk  If you are trying to fbemitter, you are requiring the wrong module. The first line should be `var {EventEmitter} = require('fbemitter');` since that is the name of the package. You also don't need to include a relative path to node_modules. It will check there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I typed `npm install emitter`, should of been `npm install fbemitter'. What threw me was there were no error messages that made this obvious, looks like the core API calls are same in both packages. At least for`addListener()`and`emit()`.

Once I checked the version # and github URL in `package.json' I figured this out quick.